# How to add an empty page in asp.net reporting services

Tags: reporting-services, report, reporting, rdlc

I am working on rdlc reports in asp.net. What my company wants me to do is to leave an empty page only after the first page since they are printing it two-side. The content is in tablix group and I somehow need to add an empty page only after the first page/ first group item (there are lots of group items coming from SQL). Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to achieve this inside an RDLC report will be a huge pain.

An easy solution is to export the report to PDF as-is and insert an empty page afterwards. You could even insert the page before you save it.

Here is the code to insert an empty page to an existing PDF file.

```
String filepath = @"";
String outPutFilePath = @"";
PDFDocument doc = new PDFDocument(filepath);

// Insert empty page at 1 (previous to the second page, so after the first page).
doc.InsertPage(1);

// Save the file.
doc.Save(outPutFilePath);
```

Comment: Great!! That helped buddy! Thank you

Comment: I also want to turn on/off this code based on a checkbox click in my web page. Is it possible to do?

Comment: It sure is, just add a parameter to the print method where you give the value of the checkbox (boolean) and wrap an if statement around the  `InsertPage` method. Should be pretty straightforward.